# How to keep index when merging two dataframes in r

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
> df1:
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 2 4
4 3 4
5 4 4
> df2:
  a b
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 2 3
4 3 4
5 5 5
```

Then merge df1 and df2 to get df3, please notice merge `by=c("a","b")`

```
df3<-merge(df1,df2)
> df3
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

I would like to get the index of rows in df1 which are selected, and add a column call "label" in df1.

```
   > df1:
      a b label    
    1 1 2  TRUE
    2 2 3  TRUE
    3 2 4 FALSE
    4 3 4  TRUE
    5 4 4 FALSE
```

I tried this:

```
df1$label<-apply(df1,1,function (x) ifelse(nrow(merge(x,df3))>0,TRUE,FALSE))
```

got the wrong result and it's very slow since my df1 is very large.
Is there any easy way? like is.element in vectors? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge on `a` and `b` by doing the equivalent of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL, and then assign non-matching rows the value `FALSE`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,3,4), b=c(2,3,4,4,4))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,3,5), b=c(1,2,4,5))
df2$label <- TRUE                                  # df1 matches to df2 is TRUE
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("a", "b"), all.x=TRUE) # merge on a AND b 
df3$label[is.na(df3$label)] <- FALSE               # non-match is FALSE
```

Output:

```
> df3
  a b label
1 1 2  TRUE
2 2 3  TRUE
3 2 4 FALSE
4 3 4  TRUE
5 4 4 FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is I need merge by "a" and "b", not just "a". if add another row in df2, like '1 1', then it'll be labeled as TRUE, which should be FALSE.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure 'df3$a' gives the index of matching rows. I just edited my question, could you check it please?

Comment: Hi @xinyiFu I have updated again according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), a)                     ## (1)
idx = df1[df2, which=TRUE, nomatch=0L]    ## (2)
df1[, label := FALSE][idx, label := TRUE] ## (3)
df1
#    a b label
# 1: 1 2  TRUE
# 2: 2 3 FALSE
# 3: 3 4  TRUE
# 4: 4 5 FALSE
```

1. `setDT` converts data.frame to data.table by reference. And on the data.table, we `setkey` on column `a` - which basically reorders the data.table *df1* by column `a` and *marks* that column as sorted. This is a prerequisite for join done in step 2.
2. We perform a join of the form `x[i]` where `x=df1` and `i=df2`. `x` has to be a *keyed* data.table and `i` can be a list, data.frame or data.table. The join is performed on the key column `a`. For each row of column `a` of *df2*, we find the matching rows, and return them by using the argument `which=TRUE`, and if there is a no match, we return a "0" for that row using `nomatch=0L`.

   At this step, we get `idx = 1, 3, 0`. Because, "1" and "3" matches the first and third rows, and "5" has no match.
3. We set the entire `label` column to `FALSE` and update only those rows of `idx` to `TRUE` (those are the matching rows). This is done by reference once again (for speed and memory efficiency) using the `:=` operator.

Have a look at the [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset if big, you can also try `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setkey(setDT(df2),a)[df1][,c('label','b') := 
                       list(!is.na(b), i.b)][,i.b:= NULL][]
 #    a b label
 #1: 1 2  TRUE
 #2: 2 3 FALSE
 #3: 3 4  TRUE
 #4: 4 5 FALSE
```